# DbSet<MyModel> property got null value when there is no physical table of MyModel?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

(.Net core 3.1)

I have a model class. And I want to fill a list of the model class with data read from a SQL query. There is no physical table with name of `MyModel`.

```
public class MyModel { 
    string A { get; set; }
    string B { get; set; }
    string C { get; set; }
}
```

And the following DbContext class

```
public calss MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<MyModel> MyModels { get; }

    public IEnumerable<MyModel> GetSomeValue(int x)
    {
       foreach (var i in MyModels.FromSqlRaw(sql)) // MyModels is always null
       {
       }
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Ignore<MyModel>();
        modelBuilder.Entity<MyModel>().HasKey(x => new { x.A, x.B });
    }
}
```

However, the property `MyModels` is always null and thus `MyModels.FromSqlRaw()` got error. How to run raw sql to fill the `MyModels` with values from the database?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out `public DbSet<MyModel> MyModels { get; }` cannot be readonly. Adding `set;` resolved the problem.

Comment: Because it cant be set out side the constructor